# Access the data from locked table in postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mvc

I have a `master_tbl`. I am trying to read the data from `master_tbl` through web service and show it on dashboard. Other web service is continuously inserting the data into `master_tbl`.

Now When I read data continuously with time 1sec from database. It shows proper value and after sometime it shows null value. It happens alternatively.

`SELECT floor_no FROM master_table order by id DESC limit 1;`

This query in web service that return the last row entered into `master_table`.

Can you help me that it is due to database locking or something else..? 
Because the point is if I execute above query and if no entry is added into `master_tbl` then it should return previous entry made in table but not null.

Following is spring controller code for calling and getting data from web service

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getfloorNo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String getfloorNo() throws IOException, NullPointerException{      
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String url = "http://localhost:8080/master_tbl/floorNo/lastdata/";          
String lastdata = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
System.out.println("floorNo: "+lastdata);  //It altenatively shows proper & null value.
return users;
}
```

And this is my json response

```
floorNo:[{"floorNo":"01","datetime":"2017-04-05 12:33:26.266"}] 
floorNo:[{"floorNo":"01","datetime":"2017-04-05 12:33:26.266"}]
floorNo:[{"floorNo":"01","datetime":"2017-04-05 12:33:26.266"}]
floorNo: null
floorNo: null
floorNo: null
```

Comment: Can you break this down into a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

From your description I understood that rows are inserted concurrently and sometimes you get null, sometimes some value when you

```
SELECT floor_no FROM master_table order by id DESC limit 1;
```

also:

> if no entry is added into master_tbl then it should return previous
>   entry made in table but not null.

leads me to idea that you want last no null value, then you should:

```
SELECT floor_no FROM master_table WHERE floor_no is not null order by id DESC limit 1;
```